# How to call to another controller passing all the params in Grails (to update the associated table in the same form)

Tags: grails

I'm working with the domain class Alojamiento, and its generated controller and views. **The next code works:**

I have included in the form of a **view** another form:

```
<g:render template="../caracteristicas/form" bean="${params.caracteristicasInstance}" />
```

Now, the **edit** action of the **controller** has:

```
def alojamientoInstance = Alojamiento.get(id)
def caracteristicasInstance = alojamientoInstance.caracteristicas
[caracteristicasInstance: caracteristicasInstance,
```

And to the **update** action of the controller:

```
def caracteristicasInstance = Caracteristicas.get(id)
caracteristicasInstance.properties = params
caracteristicasInstance.save(flush: true)
```

As I said, the above code works, but it is not protected against errors, so I'm trying to use the update action of CaracteristicasController (I'm following this approach: http://stuff4j.blogspot.com.es/2011/04/calling-controller-method-from-another.html). **The next code does NOT work, but I think it explain itself what I'm trying**:

```
CaracteristicasController caracteristicasController = new CaracteristicasController()
CaracteristicasController.properties = params
CaracteristicasController.params.doNotRedirect = 'true' // See: http://stuff4j.blogspot.com.es/2011/04/calling-controller-method-from-another.html
CaracteristicasController.update()
```

By the way, the error of Grails is: "Cannot set read-only property: properties"

**UPDATE 1**

I think I didn't explain something well. I have in _form.gsp 3 embedded _form.gsp (I said in my question 1 to simplify). So when I edit _form.gsp, the others must be updated too. I want to call the update action of the "child" controllers to update the forms, but not move to them. I want to keep being in the "parent" controller so when everything updates, the show.gsp of the "parent" will appear. Do I explain it better now?

Comment: I haven't ever seen properties in a Controller, it sounds pretty extrange. If you look at your code, in the code that works you're setting the properties of a Caracteristicas instance, but in the non-working code you're trying to set the properties of a CaracteristicasController, it's way different

Comment: You're right Eylen, it is not possible to use properties with controllers (and that's way it is not working). But the question is: how to do it then?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do... You want to show a form for Alojamiento and Caracteristicas and in the update method save the Caracteristicas and in case of error what would you want to do?
In any case, I think is better to use redirect, chain or forward as @mr-cat said

Comment: Maybe chain will work. I'm following this approach: http://stuff4j.blogspot.com.es/2011/04/calling-controller-method-from-another.html

Comment: if there are any error the auto-generated update methods of the "child" controllers will capture them. That's the idea.

Comment: I think that the post you linked is not completed, try with chain or redirect to change between controllers

Comment: I updated my question (UPDATE 1). I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: The only solution that comes to my mind right now is to make the submits via ajax, so you can call the subsequent updates without reloading.

Comment: When you say Ajax, it could be JQuery?

Comment: By the way, if I use JQuery, I should move to logic of it to a service, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, when I say ajax you can use plain javascript, jquery or other frameworks. And for your second question... you'll still need the controllers, because they're the ones that receive the http request, you could move the logic to a service,  but you can't remove the controllers

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you [redirect](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Controllers/redirect.html) or [chain](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Controllers/chain.html) with all need params?

Comment: Redirect is not an option for me because it would move to the view of the other controller. I tried `chain(controller: "caracteristicas", action: "update", params: params`, but I get **HTTP Status 405 - The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource**. Maybe I have to use the argument _model_ somehow? I don't understand why this argument is for.
 @eylen

Comment: Controllers are for manage views, move business logic to services and give up your idea to call controllers one from another

Comment: I'm agree with you suggestion MrCat, but I think it is not the point now. It actually looks that I didn't explain my question well: I updated my question (UPDATE 1)

Comment: but chain looks perfect for this purpose? why this error? what is model for? Sorry for my curiosity...

Comment: 405 is because of http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Controllers/allowedMethods.html

Comment: The caracteristicas controller has `static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]` so I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Man, http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html. As you see from allowedMethods only POST allowed for update. While redirect or chain you send GET

Comment: fyi: your links are dead. That's why it's discouraged putting just links in an answer.